# Help needed following an upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, mouse, eclipse

I upgraded to 18.04 this morning.
Eclipse now clears my java program window when I move the mouse.
When I stop moving the mouse, the program is re-displayed a few seconds later.
Can anyone help or make a suggestion to fix this? My previous Ubuntu was 16 something and I had no problems like this with it. I can always re-install a previous LTS but I'd rather not, especially if there is a known solution to this bug. 
The Graphics is AMD Oland, and I have installed the latest AMD graphics drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I reverted to 16.04, and I'm still using it. It serves my purposes, works well, and if I can't reliably upgrade to 18.04 then I shall stay with it as long as I can.